# Generating burst signals with RedPitaya

Tags: python, redpitaya

I am utilizing RedPitaya for my master project. The objective of my project is to produce droplets from a piezoelectric droplet generator by generating burst and impulse signals. The pulses within the burst should have a frequency range of 1-5MHz, while the signal's overall frequency (related to the distance between bursts) should be about 200Hz.

when I use python, I can only achieve acceptable results when using frequencies below 1MHz. Above this frequency, the signals get distorted, or their amplitude significantly decreases. Similarly, when I use C programming, the same issue occurs while in Arbitrary mode (RP-Waveform-Arbitrary). However, The quality of the signal is satisfactory when I use predefined functions (like Rp-Waveform-Sine along with burst mode), but I cannot produce the desired signal shapes, such as bursts in the form of a normal bell curve or a mixture of impulse and burst when using pre-defined functions.

I have been struggling with this issue for several months, and I have not been able to find a solution. I would greatly appreciate it if you could assist me in resolving this problem.

I expected to have a clear and good signal from RedPitaya at e.g. 4MHz, but neither python nor C could give me that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.